# Why does not the pandas.DataFrame.plot() reflect the both of style and colormap?

Tags: pandas

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

Size = 100
Num = 10

x = np.random.normal(0,1,(Num,Size))

df = DataFrame()

for i in range(Num):
    df[str(i)] = x[i]
```

And if I type

```
df.plot(colormap="jet")
```

I got the color-mapped and line-marked figure.

And if I type

```
df.plot(colormap="jet",style="o")
```

I got the the figure only marked by "o".The colormap is not reflected on the figure.

I want the figure color-mapped by "jet" and marked by "o".

Can someone solve this problem ?
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `marker` instead of `style`, then you will get points with the correct colormap:

```
df.plot(colormap="jet", marker="o")
```

I think this is because `style` overrides the color/colormap, as you can also specify the color in the style keyword.

Comment: Thanks! 
     df.plot(colormap="jet", marker="o")
has still a connection between the markers.
If we want to delete the line, what we should do?

Comment: You can add `linestyle='none'` to delete those